# Use AntiForgeryToken when form was fetched using AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-tabs

---------------Update, scroll down for original question----------------------

These two settings (which I simply did not notice) in the $.ajax call were breaking it for me:

```
contentType: false,
processData: false
```

Ajax posts with AntiForgeryTokens in dynamically-generated forms works fine when these 2 settings are removed and the AntiForgeryToken is generated in the PartialView as stated in the comment by Stephen Muecke.  The successful $.ajax call looks like this, where __RequestVerificationToken comes from a call to @HtmlAntiForgeryToken() in the partial view:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/MyUrl',
    type: "POST",
    data: {__RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
          },
    success: function (responseText) {
    ...and etc
```

----------Original question below------------------------------------------

Is it possible to use the AntiForgeryToken on a form which is dynamically-loaded via an ajax call?

In my asp.net mvc application I'm using Jquery tabs.  When the page loads I load the first tab only.  This first tab always contains a form, and this form always contains an AntiForgeryToken.  The other tabs are lazy-loaded, via ajax calls when the user selects them.

If I post back from this first tab (using a form submit or an ajax post) I use ValidateAntiForgeryToken on the Controller method, and it works fine. I can post back the entire form, or append the value of the __RequestVerificationToken hidden input to the data being posted. Either approach works fine on this first tab.

The problem comes when I post from any of the other tabs.

If a user selects any of the other tabs this causes a javascript method to fire, which in turns makes an ajax GET call to a Controller method, which in turn returns a PartialView.  This PartialView contains a form. In the success event of the ajax GET call I display the html returned by the Controller method by calling jquery html().  I then pass the dynamically-generated form through $.validator.unobtrusive.parse so that I can use unobtrusive validation.  All of this works fine.

The sole problem is that when I post back to the server from this dynamically-generated form I want to decorate the Controller method with the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute.  Alas, when I do so I get an HttpAntiForgeryException.

I've tried including the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() call inside the dynamically-generated form (that is, inside the PartialView).  This generates the expected __RequestVerificationToken hidden input, but when I pass this value back to the Controller it results in an HttpAntiForgeryException.

I've also tried fetching the __RequestVerificationToken from the first tab, thinking maybe that is what the Controller is "expecting."  Alas, that also results in an HttpAntiForgeryException.

Is there any way to use the AntiForgeryToken/ValidateAntiForgeryToken when I post back from one of these lazy-loaded, ajax-generated forms?

Comment: This is security theater, anyone wanting to steal the content can scrape the token and submit it with the request

Comment: That will work fine if `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` is included in the partial view. What is the actual error being thrown (there are 2 main ones for `HttpAntiForgeryException`)

Comment: @Derek:  1) the token changes with each request and is generated by the server.  Submitting a token from a previous "Scrape" will result in an exception.  2)  there is a corresponding cookie that is also submitted from the user's browser that is used in validating the token.  If the values don't match or are not there, the request still fails.  Is it bullet proof?  Probably not but this is far from security theater.

Comment: @Tommy I manage scrappers that do this daily. I scrape the token and use it then throw it and repeat.

Comment: @Derek - so you are saying that you can take a properly coded asp.net MVC site using this token method, create a web page on a different domain, have the users enter data into your fake site and cross post it back to a legitimate website?  You should probably alert Microsoft to this as its a huge security vulnerability and you will probably be rewarded.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @Tommy Yes. I use a curl intermediary script to handle all the actions from my site through the target site

Comment: This isn't a Microsoft issue, this is a general issue that all sites face. Its security theater at best and pointless at its worse. Anyone worth their salt can defeat this with little effort.

Comment: @StephenMuecke please post your comment as the answer.  The AntiForgeryToken needs to be rendered in the partial view.  I also noticed two settings which were breaking my call, I added them to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely possible and done by serializing form data dynamically to pass `AntiForgeryToken` with each Ajax call.

```
var data = $('#yourForm').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "@Url.Action("yourMethod", "yourController")",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        // Your code here
    }
});
```

Using the `Network` tab in Chrome, you will see that the token is attached to the Ajax call. If you place a Breakpoint in your method, you should see that you are actually able to reach in.

Comment: Thanks @Alfred, and this works fine in the "first" tab as described in the question, but this does not work in the "other," lazy-loaded tabs.  I expected this approach to work in the lazy-loaded tabs like it does in the "first" tab, but it does not, and I've no idea why.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the beginning of your action so you can freeze execution and debug in Chrome. What do you see in 'Form Data' when you show `Network`? Do you see `__RequestVerificationToken` along with the other data fields?

Comment: I was breaking it by including "contentType: false, processData: false" in the ajax call. I leapt to the conclusion that the problem was caused by the way the form was rendered.